# Unable to get the selected text from a Text Box Using JavaScript ? Works in Firefox and not in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom-events

I am trying to select the particular text which is selected in the Text box.It works fine in Firefox and not working in IE.

My Code was ,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Selection</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function displayText()
{
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var t = text.value.substr(text.selectionStart,text.selectionEnd-text.selectionStart);
  alert(t);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
 
<INPUT type="button" onclick="displayText()" value="Select text and click here" />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please give your suggestions. Am I missing anything in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ie, it is

```
document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
```

Try the updated function:

```
function displayText()
{
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  var t;
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    t = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
  } else {
    t = text.value.substr(text.selectionStart,text.selectionEnd-text.selectionStart)
  }

  alert(t);
}
```